# Javascript to calculate a submission form with radio checkbox and dropdown items

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button, submission

I'm trying to make a form calculate a total as items are selected from a mix of radio/dropdown/chekcbox and display the total at the bottom and have the ability to submit the form.

This is what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/XD8RW/1430/
The total wont show up in the middle section when you click the different options

`   
        Pricing

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="column-left">
        <p><b><u>Small ornaments (2 5/8")</u></b>

            <br>Basic figure - $6.50
            <br>(crane, pig, ball, flower etc.)
            <br>Complex figure- $7.50
            <br>(Dragon, skateboard, turkey etc.)
            <br>Foil figures - $8.50
            <br>(Anything made with foil paper)
            <br>Money Figure - $8.50
            <br>(Figures Made out of a $1 bill)
            <br>
            <br>    <b><u>Large ornaments (4")</u></b>

            <br>Basic figure - $8
            <br>(crane, pig, ball, flower etc.)
            <br>Complex figure- $9
            <br>(Dragon, skateboard, turkey etc.)
            <br>Foil figures - $10
            <br>(Anything made with foil paper)
            <br>Money Figure - $10
            <br>(Figures Made out of a $1 bill)
            <br>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="column-center">
        <form action="" id="orderform" onsubmit="return false;">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Make your ornament!</legend>
                <label><u>Size Of the Ornament</u>

                </label>
                <br>
                <input type="radio" name="selectedornament" value="small" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Small Ornament (2 5/8") - $6.50
                <input type="radio" name="selectedornament" value="small" onclick="calculateTotal()" />Large Ornament (4") - $8.50
                <br>
                <label>Figure</label>
                <select id="figure" name='figure' onchange="calculateTotal()">
                    <option value="None">Select Figure</option>
                    <option value="Crane">Crane ($0.50)</option>
                    <option value="Pig">Pig ($0.50)</option>
                    <option value="Baseball">Baseball ($0.50)</option>
                    <option value="Basketball">Basketball ($0.50)</option>
                    <option value="Flower">Flower ($0.50)</option>
                    <option value="Dragon">Dragon ($1.50)</option>
                    <option value="Skateboard">Skateboard ($1.50)</option>
                    <option value="Turkey">Turkey ($1.50)</option>
                    <option value="Cherry">Dancing Girl ($3)</option>
                    <option value="Apricot">Dollar Pig ($1.50)</option>
                    <option value="Buttercream">Dollar Shirt ($1.50)</option>
                    <option value="Chocolate Mousse">Dollar Koi ($12)</option>
                </select>
                <br/>
                <p>
                    <label for='foil' class="inlinelabel">Figure made of foil paper - ($1)</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="foil" name='foil' onclick="calculateTotal()" />
                    <br>(Except for designs made of one dollar bill)</p>
                <p>
                    <label class="inlinelabel" for='includeinscription'>Include Custom Glass Etching ($6)</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="includeinscription" name="includeinscription" onclick="calculateTotal()" />
                    <input type="text" id="theinscription" name="theinscription" value="Enter Inscription" />
                </p>
                <div id="totalPrice"></div>
                <input type='submit' id='submit' value='Submit' onclick="calculateTotal()" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="column-right">
        <p align="center"><b><u>*NOTE*</u></b>

            </center>
            <p>
                <br>I generally don't charge extra for exterior paint unless you want something very detail-oriented or a design that would consume a large ammount of my paint/require me to buy additional paint colors (I only have red white and green paints for the holidays)
                <br>Some figures are size/paper specific
                <br>Money figures are limiited as to what can/can't be made, as are foiled figures as the foiled paper is sometimes difficult to work with
                <br>When you contact me to place an order, I'll send you an e-mail back with pricing information specifically for your order</p>
    </div>
```

the js is in the jsfiddle form
sorry if i posted this wrong im new to stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like che-azeh said, there are some variables that are don't match up.
You want to user the array of selectedornaments (theForm.elements["selectedornament"]). Here named selectedCake (you might want to change that). And size_prices should be the array you have defined as ornament_prices.
Works on http://jsfiddle.net/XD8RW/1432/

```
function getOrnamentSizePrice() {
    var ornamentSizePrice = 0;
    //Get a reference to the form id="orderform"
    var theForm = document.forms["orderform"];
    //Get a reference to the size the user Chooses name=selectedOrnament":
    var selectedCake = theForm.elements["selectedornament"];
    //there are 2 radio buttons selectedornament.length = 2
    //loop through each radio buttons
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedCake.length; i++) {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if (selectedCake[i].checked) {
            //we set ornamentSizePrice to the value of the selected radio button
            //by using the ornament_prices array
            //and get the selected Items value
            ornamentSizePrice = ornament_prices[selectedCake[i].value];
            //If its a match then break out of this loop
            //No reason to continue
            break;
        }
    }
    //return the ornamentSizePrice
    return ornamentSizePrice;
}
```

Though you will want to double check the values your ornament_prices array

Answer (score 0):

Check your code against a web console like that of Firefox (`ctrl+shift+k`). You'll notice you have several undefined variables like `selectedornament` and`size_prices` which are messing things up for you. You can also use it to check for other errors.

Comment: Still not following. I don't know much about js and have a read-from-a-book teacher for a required class. He hasn't taught us anything all semester and tomorrow expects a group project. I'm trying to put together this page. I tried to copy a js form and using the provided instructions tried to mod it, but i cant make heads or tails of any of it. I've spent over five hours trying to figure it out and trying to learn and understand this mess on my own.